# How to proceed for BOW creation From sift features

Tags: matlab, sift

I extracted sift feature to construct a bag-of-words model. I did the following to extract the feature vector:

1. Extracted features from the key frames.
2. After the feature extraction I tried using Principle Component Analysis to reduce the size of my features.

Query: What further pre-processing steps should I take before creating a codebook out of the set of features extracted ?

Comment: People will be much more willing to help you if they can see some effort on your part to solve the problem yourself. Simply asking for for a solution without any evidence of any personal research is a little presumptuous.

Comment: Thank you for the response, but i studied the state of the art, the thing is that there are many issues and i dont know the best choice !!!

Comment: The work i'm doing is basically in the feature extraction step, i have done this, i extracted a space time dependant feature. It is a novel feature.

Comment: So, I need to have advices about a clustering process adapdet to the space time faeture, i thinked about K-means. Then a code book construction for video annotation.

Answer (score 1):

There is now support for the bag-of-words model in the [Computer Vision System Toolbox for MATLAB](http://www.mathworks.com/help/vision/examples/image-category-classification-using-bag-of-features.html).

Answer (score 1):

First of all, read [this](https://www.robots.ox.ac.uk/~vgg/publications/2012/Arandjelovic12/presentation.pdf). Then:

Due to the nature of this question, I will **only** give you some hints on pre-processing to improve your retrieval task.

1. Don't use Sift. Use RootSift. This is a performance gain at no cost. It is taking the square root of Sift vectors and applying L1 normalization.
2. You can use [Harris Affine regions](http://www.robots.ox.ac.uk/~vgg/research/affine/det_eval_files/mikolajczyk_ijcv2004.pdf) to even be more robust.
3. [VLAD](http://www.axes-project.eu/wp-content/uploads/2013/08/arandjelovic13.pdf) generally improves BoW model with a very simple procedure.
4. You can apply your PCA not on BoW but on this VLAD vectors.
5. Finally, you can always use a more clever quantization scheme such as product quantization.

Answer (score 0):

There is quite a bit of research showing that neither the features nor the method to build a dictionary matter that much in comparison to later encoding and pooling layers in the architecture. Have a look at these two articles.

- [The Importance of Encoding Versus Training with Sparse Coding and Vector Quantization](http://www.cs.stanford.edu/~acoates/papers/coatesng_icml_2011.pdf) and [Code](http://www.cs.stanford.edu/~acoates/papers/sc_vq_demo.tgz).
- [An Analysis of Single-Layer Networks in Unsupervised Feature Learning](http://www.cs.stanford.edu/~acoates/papers/coatesleeng_aistats_2011.pdf) and [Code](http://www.cs.stanford.edu/~acoates/papers/kmeans_demo.tgz)